# polymer automatic includes of components after bower install

Tags: polymer, bower

I would like to know if there is a way of automatically include the components after installing them with bower. Or better: automatic include and install after just writing `<app-header></app-header>` like Eclipse does it for you.

like: `bower install --save PolymerElements/app-layout`

and after that get

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
```

in all relevant files.

Comment: As of now i haven't seen any such plugin for any IDE/text-editor. If someone decides to create such plugin it might make IDE pretty heavy. What exactly do you mean by all relevant files.

Comment: When I am programming Java in Eclipse and I decide to install a specific libary, then I put it GUI-Supported into my build-path (which could be bower.json in root) after that I Eclipse reminds me to import specific libaries to my code when I use them. In that case unown classes are underlined. I can simply click on one button and tada, its imported.